# graph of $f$ dividing rectangle area.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all the monotone increasing functions $f(x),x\in(0,\infty)$ that satisfy the following:
> for every $x>0$ the rectangle $(0,f(x)),(0,0),(x,0),(x,f(x))$ is divided by the graph of the function to two parts where one of them has double the area of the other

I've set the following equation $\int_{0}^{x}f(s)ds=2\int_{0}^{x}f(x)-f(s)ds\to 3y-3c=2xy'$ and then solving this equation and the second one is the in the same way if the upper area is the larger.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on track except for the $c$, which isn't necessary since we're working with definite integrals.

To make things clearer, instead of jumping to notation involving $y$, start by defining $F(x)=\int_0^xf(s)ds$. Then your integral equation is equivalent to $F(x)=2xF'(x)-2F(x)$. Note that you also have the initial condition $F(0)=\int_0^0f(s)ds=0$.

Comment: Ok, and after I solve both of the equation I just need to eliminate the functions who are not monotone increasing right?

Comment: Right. That'll probably rule out one of the cases arising from the absolute value in $\int \frac {y'}y=\ln |y|+C$.

Comment: For this equation you should end up with $f(x)=A\sqrt{x}$, where $A$ is any positive constant.

Comment: got it thank you :)